Prove that this sequence is eventually one
Let $ \ \mathbb{N} = \{ 0,1,2,3,4,...\} \, $, $ \ O = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : n \text{ is odd} \} \ $ and $ \ T: O \to O \ $ be such that, for all $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \, $,
\begin{align*}
T(8n+1) & = 6n+1 \\
T(8n+3) & = 12n+5 \\
T(8n+5) & = 2n+1 \\
T(8n+7) & = 12n+11
\end{align*}
For each $ \ n \in O$, let $ \ S(n) = \big( n, T(n) , T(T(n)), T(T(T(n))), ... \big)$.

Prove that $S(n)$ is eventually $1$, for all $ \ n \in O \, $.


A sequence of real numbers $ \ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4, ...) \ $ is eventually $ \, c \, $ if, and only if, there exists $ \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ $ such that $ \ x_n = c \, $, for all $ \ n > N$.

My attempt: I tried to separate classes where this function were closed.
\begin{align*}
T(8n+1) & = 6n+1 & = & \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{ll}
8 \cdot (3k) +1 \ , & n=4k \ ; \\
8 \cdot (3k) +7 \ , & n=4k+1 \ ; \\
8 \cdot (3k+1) +5 \ , & n=4k+2 \ ; \\
8 \cdot (3k+2) +3 \ , & n=4k+3 \ .
    \end{array}  
                     \right. \\
T(8n+3) & = 12n+5 & = & \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{ll}
8 \cdot (3k) +5 \ , & n=2k \ ; \\
8 \cdot (3k+2) +1 \ , & n=2k+1 \ .
    \end{array}  
                     \right. \\
T(8n+5) & = 2n+1 & = & \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{ll}
8k+1 \ , & n=4k \ ; \\
8k+3 \ , & n=4k+1 \ ; \\
8k+5 \ , & n=4k+2 \ ; \\
8k+7 \ , & n=4k+3 \ .
    \end{array}  
                     \right. \\
T(8n+7) & = 12n+11 & = & \left\{ 
    \begin{array}{ll}
8 \cdot (3k+1) +3 \ , & n=2k \ ; \\
8 \cdot (3k+2) +7 \ , & n=2k+1 \ .
    \end{array}  
                     \right. \\
\end{align*}
But I failed and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Well, no idea if it works but:  a common approach to Collatz is simple induction.  Just suppose that you have proven the desired claim up to $n-1$.  Then, if $n$ ever gets to a smaller value, you are done for $n$.  So...for your function, can you prove that every starting value eventually gets to a smaller number?

It is the same problem as this: T(n)=n/2 for even n, T(n)=n-1 if n is 5 mod 8 and T(n)=3n+1 for other odd n.

Roughly  the cases are $T(k)\approx \tfrac{2}{3}k$, $T(k)\approx \tfrac{3}{2}k$, $T(k)\approx \tfrac{1}{4}k$, and $T(k)\approx \tfrac{3}{2}k$. So on average the sequence should decrease to the fixed point $1$. Of course for the Collatz conjecture this argument says the sequence increases ….

@BartMichels how can I prove this is the same problem?

Take $T_1(n)=n/2$ for $n$ even. $T_1(n)=n-1$ if $n=8k+5$ and $T_1(n)=3n+1$ if $n$ is any other odd and apply it to $n=8k+1,3,5,7$; for example $T_1(8k+1)=24k+4$ so $T_1^{(3)}(8k+1)=6k+1$; similarly $T_1^{(2)}(8k+3)=12k+5, T_1^{(3)}(8k+5)=2k+1, T_1^{(2)}(8k+7)=12k+11$ this shows that all the orbits of $T$ are included in the orbits of $T_1$ for odd numbers and conversely the odd orbits of $T_1$ coming from odd numbers are included in the orbits of $T$ so the problems of the orbits stabilizing at $1$ for $T$ and of reaching $1$ (hence becoming the $1,4,2,1$ cycle) for $T_1$ are equivalent

I'm going to take real-analysis off the list of tags, as it doesn't really apply I don't think. If you disagree, you can put it back, but you might add some explanation as to why it fits.

If I understand the notation in the question, this might be an approach, which was inspired by the comment of @lulu.
Firstly, for $T\left(8n+1\right)$ and
$T\left(8n+5\right)$ the value of the function is always smaller than the argument.  For example, if $n=1$, we have $T\left(8 \times 1+1=9\right)=6 \times 1 +1 =7$, i.e $T\left(9\right)=7$ and so forth.  Call these functions $T_{1}$ and $T_{3}$, based on the order shown in the question.
The transition conditions for $T_{1}$ are the following:
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
6n+1=8m+1
$$
$$
m=\frac{3}{4}n
$$
This produces integer $m$ for $n$ that are multiples of $4.$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
6n+1=8m+3
$$
$$
\frac{3n-1}{4}=m
$$
This is produces integer $m$ for $n=\left(3,7,11, \ldots\right)$.
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
6n+1=8m+5
$$
$$
\frac{3n-2}{4}=m
$$
This produces integer $m$ for $n=\left(2,6,10, \ldots\right).$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
6n+1=8m+7
$$
$$
\frac{3\left(n-1\right)}{4}=m
$$
This produces integer $m$ for $n=\left(1,5,9, \ldots\right).$
The transition conditions for $T_{3}$ are as follows:
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
2n+1=8m+1
$$
$$
\frac{n}{4}=m
$$
Integer values for $m$ occur when $n=\left(0,4,8, \ldots\right).$
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
2n+1=8m+3
$$
$$
\frac{n-1}{4}=m
$$
Integer values for $m$ occur when $n=\left(1,5,9, \ldots \right).$
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
2n+1=8m+5
$$
$$
\frac{n-2}{4}=m
$$
Integer values for $m$ occur when $n=\left(2,6,10,\ldots \right).$
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
2n+1=8m+7
$$
$$
\frac{n-3}{4}=m
$$
Integer values for $m$ occur when $n=\left(3,7,11, \ldots \right).$
Now, suppose we end up hitting one of the other two functions, $T_{2}$ or $T_{4}$:
$T\left(8n+3\right)=12n+5$ or $T\left(8n+7\right)=12n+11.$  Call these $T_{2}$ and $T_{4}$
We need to show that the function value of $T_{2}$ equals the argument of $T_{1}$ or $T_{3}$ for some $m \ge n.$
For example for mapping to $T_{1}$, $12n+5=8m+1?$
$$
12n+4=8m
$$
This is satisfied for $n=1, m=2$ also $n=3, m=5$, $n=5, m=8$ etc. (i.e. $n$ odd).
On the other hand, $T_{2}$ will map to $T_{3}$ for $n$ even:
$$
12n+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12n=8m
$$
This is satisfied for $n=0, m=0; n=2, m=3; n=4, m=6; n=6, m=9$ etc.
We note that the value of $T_{2}$ represents a local maximum in that the value of the next function will be less than the value of $T_{2}.$  In particular:
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
6m+1 \lt 12n+5
$$
$$
6\frac{12n+4}{8}+1 \lt 12n+5
$$
$$
6\left(12n+4\right)+8 \lt 96n+40
$$
$$
72n+32 \lt 96n+40
$$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
2m+1 \lt 12n+5
$$
$$
2\frac{12n}{8}+1 \lt 12n+5
$$
$$
24n+8 \lt 96n+40
$$
Now, we need to show how $T_{4}$ maps.  For example, $T_{4}$ maps to $T_{2}$ under the following conditions:
$$
12n+11=8m+3
$$
$$
12n+8=8m
$$
This satisfied for $n=0, m=1; n=2, m=4; n=4, m=7; n=6, m=10; n=8, m=13$ etc. (i.e. $n$ even).
Now, $T_{4}$ maps to $T_{4}$ for the following cases:
$$
12n+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12n+4=8m
$$
This is satisfied for $n=1, m=2; n=3, m=5; n=5, m=8$ etc. (i.e. $n$ odd).
Since the mapping behavior of $T_{2}$ and $T_{4}$ has been apparently characterized, and it seems that $T_{2}$ or $T_{4}$ will eventually map to $T_{1}$ or $T_{3}$, this might provide some direction towards the induction approach that was suggested by @lulu in the comments.
Maximum Sequence Repeat Analysis for $T_{4}.$
In the case where the index to the argument of $T_{4}$ is of the form $4n+1$ (i.e. every other odd starting with $1$) we obtain the sequence $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}.$  In other words, the run length for $T_{4}$ will be two before transitioning to $T_{2}.$  The following will show this is the case:
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
12 \left(4n+1\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
48n+16=8m
$$
$$
6n+2=m
$$
We can see that the new index to $T_{4}, m$, is even.  Therefore, from the above analysis we know that $T_{4}$ will transition to $T_{2}$, justifying the statement above regarding the run length of $T_{4}.$
In the case where the index to the argument is $4n+3$, i.e. every other odd starting with $3$, and $n$ is even, we have the following run: $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}.$  That is, a sequence of three $T_{4}$ before transitioning to $T_{2}.$  This can be shown as follows:
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
12 \left(4n+3\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12 \left(4n+3\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
48n+40=8m
$$
$$
6n+5 = m
$$
The above is an even plus odd, which is always odd, therefore we know that at least one more $T_{4}$ must occur based on the previous analysis.
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
12\left(6n+5\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12 \left(6n+5\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
72n+64=8m
$$
$$
9n+8=m
$$
Clearly, the above will be even for $n$ even, thus showing the sequence as a run length of three $T_{4}$ before transition to $T_{2}$ as described.
For index of the form $4n+3$ and $n=\left(1,5,9,13 \ldots \right)$ we will have the sequence $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$ (i.e. 4 $T_{4}$'s in sequence before the transition to $T_{2}$).
To show this, continuing from the previous index: $m=9n+8.$
$$
12\left(9n+8\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12\left(9n+8\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
108n+100=8m
$$
Let $n=4p+1$ and substitute above:
$$
108\left(4p+1\right)+100=8m
$$
$$
432p+208=8m
$$
$$
54p+26=m
$$
This is clearly even for any integer $p$ as asserted.
For index of the form $4n+3$ and $n=\left(3,11,19, \ldots \right)$ we will have the sequence $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$ (i.e. 5 $T_{4}$'s in sequence before the transition to $T_{2}$).
To show this, we continue from above:
$$
m=\frac{108n+100}{8}
$$
$$
12 \left(\frac{108n+100}{8}\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12 \left(\frac{108n+100}{8}\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
162n+154=8m
$$
Now substitute $n=8p+3$ into the above:
$$
162\left(8p+3\right)+154=8m
$$
$$
1296p+640=8m
$$
$$
162p+80=m
$$
The above $m$ is clearly even for any $p$, therefore validating the sequence length.
In summary, for the odd index of the form $4n+3$, we have shown finite termination of the $T_{4}$ sequence for all even $n$, and for odd $n=\left(1,3,5,9,11,13,17,19,21, \ldots \right).$
To address the missing odd elements in the above sequence, of the form $n=8p+7$, we can use the following recursion (similar to the above process):
$$
8m_{d}+7=12 m_{d-1}+11
$$
or
$$
8m_{d}=12 m_{d-1}+4
$$
where $d$ is the depth of the $T_{4}$ sequence.  In other words, how many repeats of $T_{4}$ are there before transitioning to $T_{2}$.  The idea is to find the depth such that $m_{d}$ is even, which means the next function in the sequence will be $T_{2}$, thus terminating the $T_{4}$ run.
$$
m_{d}=\frac{3}{2}m_{d-1}+\frac{1}{2}
$$
We compute the first index $m_{0}$ as:
$$
m_{0}=4 \left(8p+7\right)+3=32p+31
$$
Solving the recursion, using standard techniques (for example, please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients)
where we note that the above is an "inhomogeneous" recursion, with characteristic polynomial
$$
P\left(\lambda\right)=\lambda-\frac{3}{2}
$$
and the offset $y^{*}$ for converting to a homogeneous form given as:
$$
y^{*}=\frac{1/2}{1-3/2}=-1
.$$
From these components, one obtains:
$$
m_{d}=32 \left(p+1\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{d-1}-1
$$
Now, we need to determine for a given $p$, which is the depth $d$ such that the index $m_{d}$ is even.  Equivalently, we can determine when $m_{d}+1$ is odd.  Call this function $s$ so we have:
$$
s=32\left(p+1\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
This can be written as
$$
s=32\left(p+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}3^{d-1}
$$
Now, we need to determine when this expression $s$ is odd.  This means that we need to find the conditions when
$$
s' = 32 \left(p+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
is odd, since $3^{d-1}$ is always odd, and we can only get an odd $s$ if the remaining terms, $s'$, work out to be odd, since odd $\times$ odd is odd.
Now, suppose $p$ is even.  Then
$$
s' = 32 \left(p+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
is odd if we cancel out the $32$, by dividing by $2^{5}$ which corresponds to $d=6.$
Now, if $p$ is odd, we will have to divide $s'$ by $2$ until only an odd factor remains.  This is clearly a finite number, for any given $p$ odd.  For example, suppose $p=5$, then we have
$$
s'=32\left(5+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
$$
s'=32\left(6\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
$$
s'=32\left(2 \times 3\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{d-1}
$$
Therefore, there will be $2^{5}$ to divide out $32$ and one additional power of $2$ to cancel the factor $2$ in $2 \times 3$.  This will increase the depth by $1$ from $6$ to $7$, of course.
We observe that if $p=2^q-1$ for some positive integer $q$, we obtain a maximal number of factors of two, in addition to the baseline $5$, and a corresponding (local) maximum depth.
Example Path Tracing Starting with $T_{2}$ to Support Induction.
n even:
As an example, consider the sequence where the initial value $n$ is even and maps to the argument of $T_{2}$.  That is, the argument is $8n+3$ (for example, $19, 35$ etc.)  Now, given the above analysis, the corresponding value of $T_{2}$ will map to $T_{3}.$  The index will be $m=\frac{12n}{8}$ and the corresponding value of $T_{3}$ will be
$$
2m+1=2\frac{12n}{8}+1=3n+1.
$$
Now, $3n+1 \lt 8n+3$, which shows that this sequence will result in a value less than the starting value in two steps, which can be used in the inductive argument I believe.
n odd:
Suppose the index is odd of the form $8n+1.$  This will lead to the sequence $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(8n+1\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
96n+16=8m
$$
$$
12n+2=m
$$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
6\left(12n+2\right)+1=8m+5
$$
$$
72n+8=8m
$$
$$
9n+1=m
$$
We can see that $2\left(9n+1\right)+1=18n+3 \lt 8\left(8n+1\right)+3=64n+11$, therefore we arrive at a value less than the original argument of $T_{2}.$
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+3.$  If $n$ is of the form $n=4p+3$, there will be a sequence of $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$ for a total depth of five.  We show this now.
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
We know that for an odd index, there will be a transition to $T_{1}.$
$$
12 \left(8\left(4p+3\right)+3\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
12 \left(32p+27\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
384p+328=8m
$$
$$
48p+41=m
$$
The above $m$ is always odd and corresponds to a form $4q+1$ which will transition to $T_{4}$ as described in an earlier analysis.
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
6\left(48p+41\right)+1=8m+7
$$
$$
6\left(48p+41\right)-6=8m
$$
$$
288p+240=8m
$$
$$
36p+30=m
$$
The above $m$ is always even, so the transition is to $T_{2}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12 \left(36p+30\right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
12 \left(36p+30\right)+8=8m
$$
$$
12 \left(36p+30\right)+8=8m
$$
$$
432p+368=8m
$$
$$
54p+46=m
$$
The above $m$ is always even, so the next transition is to $T_{3}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12 \left(54p+46\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12 \left(54p+46\right)=8m
$$
$$
648p+552=8m
$$
$$
81p+69=m
$$
We now show that the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{2}.$
$$
2 \left( 81p+69 \right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 8\left(4p+3\right)+3\right)+3
$$
$$
162p+139 \lt 8 \left( 32p+27\right)+3
$$
$$
162p+139 \lt 256p+219
$$
If $n$ is of the form, $n=8p+6$, we will have the following sequence:  $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}.$  We show this now:
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
We know that for an odd index, there will be a transition to $T_{1}.$
$$
12\left(8\left(8p+6\right)+3\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
12\left(64p+51\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
768p+616=8m
$$
$$
96p+77=m
$$
The above index $m$ is odd and corresponds to a sequence of the form $4q+1$ which earlier analysis shows yields a transition to $T_{4}.$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
6\left(96p+77\right)+1=8m+7
$$
$$
6\left(96p+77\right)-6=8m
$$
$$
576p+456=8m
$$
$$
72p+57=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always odd, and this produces a transition to $T_{4}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
12\left(72p+57\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12\left(72p+57\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
864p+688=8m
$$
$$
108p+86=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, thus leading to a transition to $T_{2}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(108p+86\right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
12\left(108p+86\right)+8=8m
$$
$$
1296p+1040=8m
$$
$$
162p+130=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, which will cause a transition to $T_{3}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12\left(162p+130\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12\left(162p+130\right)=8m
$$
$$
1944p+1560=8m
$$
$$
243p+195=m
$$
We now show that the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{2}.$
$$
2\left(243p+195\right)+1 \lt 8\left(8\left(8p+6\right)+3\right)+3
$$
$$
486p+391 \lt 8\left(64p+51\right)+3
$$
$$
486p+391 \lt 512p+411
$$
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+5.$  This will produce the following sequence:  $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{1}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12 \left(8n+5\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
96n+64=8m
$$
$$
12n+8=m
$$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
6 \left(12n+8 \right)+1 = 8m+1
$$
$$
72n+48=8m
$$
$$
9n+6=m
$$
We see that $6\left(9n+6\right)+1=54n+37 \lt 8 \left(8n+5\right)+3=64n+43$.  Thus, the value for $T_{1}$ is less than the starting argument for $T_{2}.$
Suppose the index is of the form $16n+7$, we get the sequence:  $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$.
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12 \left(16n+7\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
192n+88=8m
$$
$$
24n+11=m
$$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
6 \left(24n+11\right)+1=8m+3
$$
$$
144n+64=8m
$$
$$
18n+8=m
$$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12 \left(18n+8\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
216n+96=8m
$$
$$
27n+12=m
$$
So then, the value of $T_{3}$ will be $2\left(27n+12\right)+1=54n+25 \lt 8\left(16n+7\right)+3=128n+59$, thus less than the initial argument of $T_{2}.$
Now, suppose the index is of the form $16n+15$.
Even $n$:
For even $n$ there will be sequences that reaches a lower value than the initial argument after $5$ steps.
For $n=2p$ one has the sequence:
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$ followed either by $T_{3}$ or $T_{1}.$
To show this, one goes through the following calculations:
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(16\left(2p\right)+15\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
12\left(32p+15\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
384p+184=8m
$$
$$
48p+23=m
$$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
6\left(48p+23\right)+1=288p+139=8m+3
$$
$$
288p+136=8m
$$
$$
36p+17=m
$$
It should be pointed out that the only function which will yield an integer $m$ is $T_{2}$ which validates the choice.  The above $m$ is odd, so we know that $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$ in the next step.
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(36p+17\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
432p+208=8m
$$
$$
54p+26=m
$$
Now, there are two branches.  If $p$ is even, the next function is $T_{3}$, else if $p$ is odd, the next function is $T_{1}.$
To show this transition to $T_{3}$, assume $p=2q.$  Then we have:
$$
6\left(54\left(2q\right)+26\right)+1
$$
$$
6\left(108q+26\right)+1
$$
Equating to the argument of $T_{3}$:
$$
648q+157=8m+5
$$
$$
81q+19=m
$$
Thus, the above is an integer $m$ for all $q$.
Now, we need to show the value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{2}$ in order to support the induction.
$$
2\left(81q+19\right)+1=162q+39=81p+39 \lt 8 \left(16\left(2p\right)+15\right)+3=8\left(32p+15\right)+3=256p+123.
$$
To show the transition to $T_{1}$, assume now $p=2q+1.$  Then we have:
$$
6\left(54\left(2q+1\right)+26\right)+1
$$
$$
6\left(108q+80\right)+1
$$
Equating to the argument of $T_{1}$:
$$
648q+481=8m+1
$$
$$
81q+60=m
$$
Thus, the above is an integer $m$ for all $q$.
Now, we need to show the value of $T_{1}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{2}$ in order to support the induction.
$$
6\left(81q+60\right)+1=486q+361=486\left(p-1\right)/2+361 \lt 8 \left(16\left(2p\right)+15\right)+3=8\left(32p+15\right)+3=256p+123.
$$
Odd $n$:
For $n=\left(1,5,9, \ldots \right)$ we will have the following sequence:  $T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$.  We note that the first four functions in the sequence always occur for any odd $n$ then there is a branching.  This is shown by the following:
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
We note that any time the index for $T_{2}$ is odd, the next function will be $T_{1}.$  The index in this case is $16\left(2p+1\right)+15.$
$$
12\left(16\left(2p+1\right)+15\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
12\left(16\left(2p+1\right)+15\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
12\left(16\left(2p+1\right)+15\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
12\left(32p+31\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
384p+376=8m
$$
$$
48p+47=m
$$
We can see that $m$ will always be odd.  Furthermore, it corresponds to the form $4q+3$, meaning:
$$
48p+47=4q+3
$$
$$
48p+44=4q
$$
$$
12p+11=q
$$
From the previous analysis, this confirms the transition of $T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$ which is described next.
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
6\left(48p+47\right)+1=8m+3
$$
$$
288p+280=8m
$$
$$
36p+35=m
$$
We again see that $m$ is odd, and thus we will transition to $T_{1}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(36p+35\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
432p+424=8m
$$
$$
54p+53=m
$$
This $m$ is again always odd.  Now, a branching occurs between $T_{4}$ and $T_{2}.$  If $p$ is odd, we branch to $T_{2}.$  We show this here, using a similar analysis to what was done above for the earlier transition from $T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
54p+53=4q+3
$$
$$
54\left(2r+1\right)+53=4q+3
$$
$$
108r+104=4q
$$
$$
27r+26=q
$$
We note that $q$ is always an integer, however it alternates between even and odd.
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
6\left(54\left(2r+1\right)+53\right)+1=8m+3
$$
$$
6\left(54\left(2r+1\right)+53\right)-2=8m
$$
$$
6\left(108r+107\right)-2=8m
$$
$$
648r+640=8m
$$
$$
648r+640=8m
$$
$$
81r+80=m
$$
This yields an integer $m.$  Furthermore, $m$ will be alternating between even and odd.  For $r$ even, $T_{2}$ will transition to $T_{3}.$
We can see this from:
$$
12\left(81r+80\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12\left(81\left(2t\right)+80\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12\left(81\left(2t\right)+80\right)=8m
$$
$$
12\left(162t+80\right)=8m
$$
$$
12\left(162t+80\right)=8m
$$
$$
1944t+960=8m
$$
$$
243t+120=m
$$
The above $m$ is always an integer, which validates the transition to $T_{3}.$
Now we need to show that the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument of $T_{2}$ which supports the induction.
$$
2\left(243t+120\right)+1 \lt 8\left(16\left(2p+1\right)+15\right)+3
$$
$$
486t+241 \lt 8\left(32p+31\right)+3
$$
$$
486t+241 \lt 256p+251
$$
$$
243r+241 \lt 256p+251
$$
$$
243 \frac{\left(p-1\right)}{2}+241 \lt 256p+251
$$
Example Path Tracing Starting with $T_{4}$ to Support Induction.
Index even:
Now consider an example starting with $T_{4}$ and where the index is of the form $4n+2$, which is every other even integer starting with $2.$  This leads to the sequence $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}.$
Doing a similar analysis to the one above, the following is obtained.
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(4n+2\right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
48n+32=8m
$$
$$
6n+4=m
$$
We see that the index $m$ will always be even, thus we know that $T_{2}$ will map to $T_{3}$ as mentioned above.
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12 \left(6n+4\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
72n+48=8m
$$
$$
9n+6=m
$$
The value of $T_{3}$ will then be
$$
2\left(9n+6\right)+1=18n+13
$$
Now, $18n+13 \lt 8\left(4n+2\right)+7=32n+23$, the argument of $T_{4}$.  Thus we see that we arrive at a value less than the original after three steps.  Again, this supports the induction approach.
For an index of the form $16n$, we will have the sequence:  $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}$ for a sequence depth of four.  We show this now:
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(16n\right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
192n+8=8m
$$
$$
24n+1=m
$$
We see that the above index $m$ is always odd, which will transition to $T_{1}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(24n+1\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
288n+16=8m
$$
$$
36n+2=m
$$
This will transition to $T_{3}$ because $m$ is of the form $4p+2$ and this was discussed in earlier analysis.
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
6\left(36n+2\right)+1=8m+5
$$
$$
216n+8=8m
$$
$$
27n+1=m
$$
We now show that the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}.$
$$
2\left(27n+1\right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 16n \right) + 7
$$
$$
54n+3 \lt 128n + 7
$$
Index odd:
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+1.$  We will then have the following sequence:  $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}.$  We show this is the case.
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
We explained in an earlier analysis that an odd index to $T_{4}$ would cause a transition to $T_{4}.$
$$
12\left(8n+1\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
96n+16=8m
$$
$$
12n+2=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, and we know that an even index to $T_{4}$ will transition to $T_{2}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(12n+2 \right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
144n+32=8m
$$
$$
18n+4=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, and from previous analysis we know that this will cause $T_{2}$ to transition to $T_{3}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12\left(18n+4\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
216n+48=8m
$$
$$
27n+6=m
$$
We now show that the value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}$, thus supporting the induction argument.
$$
2\left(27n+6\right)+1 \lt 8 \left(8n+1 \right)+7
$$
$$
54n+13 \lt 64n+15
$$
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+3.$  For $n$ of the form $4p+1$, we will have the following sequence:  $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}.$  The last transition will alternate between $T_{1}$ and $T_{3}$ for a total depth of six.  We show this now:
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
We explained in an earlier analysis that an odd index to $T_{4}$ would cause a transition to $T_{4}.$
$$
12\left(8 \left(4p+1\right)+3\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12 \left(32p+11 \right) +4=8m
$$
$$
384p+136=8m
$$
$$
48p+17=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always odd, so we will again transition to $T_{4}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
$$
12\left(48p+17\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
576p+208=8m
$$
$$
72p+26=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, so we next transition to $T_{2}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(72p+26\right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
864p+320=8m
$$
$$
108p+40=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, so we transition to $T_{3}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
12\left(108p+40\right)+5=8m+5
$$
$$
12\left(108p+40\right)=8m
$$
$$
12\left(108p+40\right)=8m
$$
$$
162p+60=m
$$
The above index $m$ is always even, and from previous analysis, we know that the transition will be to $T_{1}$ or $T_{3}$ in every case.
For $p=2q$, we will transition to $T_{1}.$
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
2\left(162p+60\right)+1=8m+1
$$
$$
2\left(162p+60\right)=8m
$$
$$
648q+120=8m
$$
$$
81q+15=m
$$
The above $m$ is an integer for any $q.$
We now show that the final value of $T_{1}$ will be less than the initial argument to $T_{4}.$
$$
6\left(81q+15\right)+1 \lt 8\left(8\left(4p+1\right)+3\right)+7
$$
$$
486q+91 \lt 8\left(32p+11\right)+7
$$
$$
486q+91 \lt 256p+95
$$
$$
243p+91 \lt 256p+95
$$
For $p=2q+1$, we will transition to $T_{3}.$
$T_{3} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
2\left(162p+60\right)+1=8m+5
$$
$$
2\left(162p+60\right)-4=8m
$$
$$
324p+116=8m
$$
$$
324\left(2q+1\right)+116=8m
$$
$$
648q+440=8m
$$
$$
81q+55=m
$$
The above $m$ are integers for all $q$.
We now show the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}$ thus supporting the induction hypothesis.
$$
2\left(81q+55\right)+1 \lt 8\left(8\left(4p+1\right)+3\right)+7
$$
$$
162q+111 \lt 8\left(32p+11\right)+7
$$
$$
162q+111 \lt 256p+95
$$
$$
81\left(p-1\right)+111 \lt 256p+95
$$
$$
81p+30 \lt 256p+95
$$
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+5.$  For $n$ of the form $4p+2$, we will have the following sequence:  $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}.$  We show this now:
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4}$:
We explained in an earlier analysis that an odd index to $T_{4}$ would cause a transition to $T_{4}.$
$$
12\left(8 \left(4p+2\right)+5\right)+11=8m+7
$$
$$
12\left(32p+21\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
384p+256=8m
$$
$$
48p+32=m
$$
The above $m$ is always even, so this will transition to $T_{2}.$
$T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2}$:
$$
12\left(48p+32 \right)+11=8m+3
$$
$$
12\left(48p+32 \right)+8=8m
$$
$$
576p+392=8m
$$
$$
72p+49=m
$$
The above $m$ is always odd, which causes a transition to $T_{1}.$
$T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1}$:
$$
12\left(72p+49\right)+5=8m+1
$$
$$
12\left(72p+49\right)+4=8m
$$
$$
864p+592=8m
$$
$$
108p+74=m
$$
The above sequence $m$ is even, and corresponds to a form $4q+2$, where $q=27p+18.$  This implies a transition to $T_{3}.$
$T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3}$:
$$
6\left(108p+74\right)+1=8m+5
$$
$$
6\left(108p+74\right)-4=8m
$$
$$
648p+440=8m
$$
$$
81p+55=m
$$
We now show that the final value of $T_{3}$ is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}.$
$$
2\left(81p+55\right)+1 \lt 8\left(8\left(4p+2\right)+5\right)+7
$$
$$
162p+111 \lt 8\left(32p+21\right)+7
$$
$$
162p+111 \lt 256p+175
$$
Suppose the index is of the form $8n+7.$  For $n$ of the form $n=128p+2$, we will have the following sequence:  $T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{4} \rightarrow T_{2} \rightarrow T_{1} \rightarrow T_{3} \rightarrow T_{1}$.  After this common sequence, the final function will alternate between $T_{3}$ and $T_{1}.$
The analysis is similar to the above cases.  We show the final result for the cases ending in $T_{3}$ and $T_{1}$ respectively.
$T_{4} \ldots T_{3}$:
We show that the final value is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}.$
$$
2\left(2187q+25\right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 8 \left(128p+2 \right) + 7 \right) + 7
$$
$$
2\left(2187q+25\right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 8 \left(256 q +2 \right) + 7 \right) + 7
$$
$$
4374q+51 \lt 8 \left( 2048 q + 23 \right) + 7
$$
$$
4374q+51 \lt 16384q + 191
$$
$T_{4} \ldots T_{1}$:
We show that the final value is less than the initial argument to $T_{4}.$
$$
6\left(2187q+1119\right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 8 \left(128p+2 \right) + 7 \right) + 7
$$
$$
6\left(2187q+1119\right)+1 \lt 8 \left( 8 \left(128 \left(2q+1 \right)+2 \right) + 7 \right) + 7
$$
$$
13122q+6715 \lt 8 \left( 8 \left(256q+130 \right) + 7 \right) + 7
$$
$$
13122q+6715 \lt 8 \left( 2048q+1047 \right) + 7
$$
$$
13122q+6715 \lt 16384q+8383
$$
Summary of Index Branches Proven for Induction Argument.
$T_{1}:  \checkmark$
$T_{3}:  \checkmark$
$T_{2}:$
even: $\checkmark$
$8n+1: \checkmark$
$8n+3:$
$\quad n=4p+3 \checkmark$
$\quad n=8p+6 \checkmark$
$8n+5: \checkmark$
$8n+7:$
$\quad 16n+7 \checkmark$
$\quad 16n+15, \text{even}: \checkmark$
$\quad 16n+15, \text{odd}: (1,5,9,\ldots) \checkmark$
$T_{4}:$
even: $\left(2,6,10,\ldots\right), \left(0,16,32 \ldots \right) \checkmark$
$8n+1: \checkmark$
$8n+3:$
$\quad n=4p+1 \checkmark$
$8n+5:$
$\quad n=4p+2 \checkmark$
$8n+7:$
$\quad n=128p+2 \checkmark$

I upvoted for the great efforts put into this answer.
